# How does Azure Bot Channel Registration authenticate my Teams app

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

When I create a Bot Channels Registration service in Azure, and then create a Teams app that will use that, how is the Bot Channel Registration being informed what apps it should allow to go through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not authenticate the MS Teams app. Any app can point to any Bot Channels Registration or Azure Bot, it's up to the bot backend to validate the source of the message if desired. Like using one of the links in the comments of the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

The registration app ID and password added in bot configuration file. Allows the bot to be authenticated to access protected resources.

The Bot Connector service natively uses HTTPS to exchange messages between a bot and channels (users). the Bot Framework SDK automates basic bot-to-channel authentication for you.

Please have a look at this documentation - [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-security-guidelines?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) and other modules present in it.

Comment: But there's actually no authentication between the Teams App and Bot Channels Registration, right?

Comment: You can add authentication for your Teams bot - Have a look at this documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample).

Comment: You can also try and setup this sample which show [Teams authentication](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth).

Comment: I appreciate the resources but that's not what I'm asking. I'm not trying to find a solution but to understand how the connection between Teams and Bot Channels Registration works.